# ajax with selectmanymenu not working

Tags: jsf-2

I am using the selectmanymenu tag with ajax but the listner is not getting called. the same code has worked for selectonemenu without event="change". please suggest me if i am doing wrong

here is the code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
</h:head>

  <h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:selectManyMenu id="dropDownValue"
            value="#{loginBean.dropDownValue}" style="height:100px; width:100px;">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="****select***" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{loginBean.testDropDown}" />
            <f:ajax render="testDropDownTwo"
                listener="#{loginBean.changeDropDownOne}" event="change" />
        </h:selectManyMenu>

        <h:selectManyMenu id="testDropDownTwo"
            value="#{loginBean.dropDownTwoValue}"
            style="height:100px; width:100px;">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="****select***" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{loginBean.testDropDownTwo}" />
        </h:selectManyMenu>
    </h:form>

   </h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is no problem for me, you should provide your backing bean.

However, I tried your code and you may check this:

(Page is exactly the same with yours)

**Backing Bean:**

```
private List<String> dropDownValue = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> dropDownTwoValue = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> testDropDown = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> testDropDownTwo = new ArrayList<>();

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    testDropDown.add("a");
    testDropDown.add("b");
    testDropDown.add("c");
}

public void changeDropDownOne() {
    testDropDownTwo.clear();
    for(String str:dropDownValue)
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    testDropDownTwo.add(str+i);
}
//simply getters and setters below
```